# How to fetch the Windows user information in marklogic

Tags: marklogic

We have a requirement to fetch the current windows logged in user name in marklogic. Does marklogic have an api which could return this information. I have searched for the same, but could not find any api. Please let me know if there is an api or any other work around for the same.

Comment: [marklogic] has an `ENV(...)` function for returning environment variables. Use like `ENV('user')` for the current local user. See [Using Operating System Environment Variables in properties](https://github.com/marklogic/roxy/wiki/Using-Operating-System-Environment-Variables-in-properties) for more. I cannot test this solution and will restrict this to a comment but anyone is welcome to run with it on a fully tested answer.

Comment: @Jeeped that's roxy which uses Ruby. I don't know of any function that can get the current OS user. But what do you mean when you say current users. Marklogic is going to be running on a server and the OS user that is running it is going to be pretty static. Do you mean the user the send the http request?

Comment: Anu, could you elaborate about how that user name would be used? Keep in mind MarkLogic usually runs on a remote server, which might not even be Windows. If you talk about the user name of the person behind the browser that is opening a web application running in MarkLogic, you might need to use client-side code to send those details to the server..